# Sorting Array in Java by Arrays.sort;

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I implemented my own class `myclass`. I wrote following code for sorting

```
Arrays.sort(arrayForSortingInterval, new Comparator<myclass>() {
    public int compare(myclass o1, myclass o2) {
        return o1.minute <= o2.minute ? 1 : 0;
    }
});
```

My array is declared as `myclass[] arrayForSortingInterval = new myclass[lengthIntervalArray*2];`  and myclass has two integer values `minute` and `tag`.

But this sorting code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What does _doesn't seems to work_ mean? What do you expect, what do you get?

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions, classes should be in `UpperCamelCase`.

Comment: Your compare method never returns -1. Why don't you use `Integer.compare(o1.minute, o2.minute);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `compare` method needs to return a negative number when the left object is less than the right one, zero when the two are equal, and a positive number when the left object is greater than the one on the right. One way of achieving this is calling [`Integer.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) (assuming that `minute` is an `int` in your `myclass` class):

```
public int compare(myclass o1, myclass o2) {
    return Integer.compare(o1.minute, o2.minute);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your comparator is wrong. It should:  Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Answer (score 1):

You comparator method is incorrect, since it is not antisymmetric (compare a to b returns 1, then b to a returns 0).

you should simply return `o1.minute - o2.minute`

Answer (score 0):

Your compare function is incorrect `-1, 0 or 1` for less then, equals or greater respectively.

```
public int compare(myclass o1, myclass o2) {
  // return o1.minute <= o2.minute ? 1 : 0;
  if (o1.minute < o2.minute) {
    return -1;
  } else if (o1.minute > o2.minute) {
    return 1;
  }
  return Integer.compare(o1.tag, o2.tag);
}
```

Comment: @MoritzPetersen I assume OP wants to compare tag as well, otherwise why mention the field? Perhaps I over-thought it.